# How to check the value is present in the data in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

i have a column with multiple values in the cell want to check if particular value is present or not.

Example :

| data |
| --- |
| a,b,b,c,d |
| m,n,o,p |

i want to check if o is present in the column.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(<data>,"*o*")` in it's simplest form.

Comment: rather than adding value is there a way I can reference a cell to check @JvdV

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$3;"*"&C3&"*")>0;"Found";"Not Found")
```

[image]